# If $S$ spans $V$, is $\dim(S) \geq \dim(V)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If $S$ spans $V$, is $\dim(S) \geq \dim(V)$?

I'm trying to use the exchange lemma, and it said:

> Let $U$ and $W$ be finite subsets of a vector space $V$. If $U$ is a set of linearly independent vectors, and $W$ spans $V$, then:
>
> 1. $|U|\leq |W|$;
> 2. There is a set $ W'\subseteq W$ with $|W'|=|W|-|U|$ such that $U\cup W'$ spans $V$.

For the second bullet point, if $U\cup W'$ spans V, does it mean $\dim(U\cup W') \geq \dim(V)$? Or does it mean $\dim(U\cup W') = \dim(V)$?

Comment: The dimension can't be larger than that of V since $U \cup W'$ is a subspace of V

Comment: Dimension is not a property of subsets of $V$, but only of subspaces.  Thus $\operatorname{Dim}(S)$ has a priori no meaning.

Comment: Is $\dim(S)$ meaning the dimension of the subspace spanned by $S$? Or are you confusing dimension and cardinality?